# The name '****' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am realy new to coding, have been trying to make myself code for a long time and finaly I started. :)

So I have this problem:

> The name `point` does not exist in the current context

and I just couldn't understand the other "fixes", they were too difficult to understand.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Point : MonoBehaviour {

    public int point;
    public float score;

    void Start () {

    }

    void OnTriggerEngter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) 
        {
            point (1);
        }
    }
}
```

There are probably a lot of mistakes in here but I'm just a newbie.

please help. thanks!

Comment: did you try "point = 1"?

Comment: What do you expect `point (1);` to do? `point` is a field of your class, you cannot _call_ it. Did you mean `point = 1;` instead?

Comment: If you found that your question is answered please mark the corresponding post. Also if you found any answer helpful please consider an upvote.

Comment: how do i mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call `point` as function but it is an `integer`. In order to assign a value to it you have to write: `point = 1`. May I suggest you have a look at various resources to begin programming like this one:

https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coding-unity-absolute-beginner